# Flutter: Loading json data within second page Flutter Class timing out without error

Tags: json, http, flutter, dart, get

I've generated a listView from the Pokemon API of a list of Pokemon, I then have onTap events to trigger a new page/class, where I'm passing the name and URL from the API to the new secondPage Class/Screen.

I need to make a second request in this new page because the API Url needs to change to grab specific details but my request seems to be timing out..

Here is my code: If loaded into a new project the first screen should function fine, loading a bunch of Pokemon and their API specific URLs into a listView.

I can successfully pass the name and URL onto the second screen because they do appear in the Appbar.

However when loading the new json data it seems to be timing out without any error.

Does anyone have any advice for a newbie trying to get his footing?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  String url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151';
  List data;

  Future<String> makeRequest() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    setState(() {
      var extractData = json.decode(response.body);
      data = extractData["results"];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.makeRequest();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Pokemon List'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: new TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Search",
                  hintText: "Search",
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0))
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
                    return new ListTile(
                      title: new Text(StringUtils.capitalize(data[i]["name"])),
                      subtitle: new Text(data[i]["url"]),
                      //  leading: new CircleAvatar(
                      // backgroundImage:
                      // new NetworkImage(data[i]["picture"]["thumbnail"]),
                      //  ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            new MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                new SecondPage(data[i])
                            )
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Class for getting Specific Details on SecondPage
class Post {
  final String name;
  final int weight;

  Post({this.name, this.weight});

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
      name: json['name'],
      weight: json['weight'],
    );
  }
}
// New Request for Specific Details
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  SecondPage(this.data);
  final data;

  Future<Post> fetchPost() async {
    final response =
    await http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + data["name"]);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON.
      return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

  Future<Post> post;

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchPost();
    post = fetchPost();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
      new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text(data["name"] + ' - ' + data["url"])),
          body: new Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  child: FutureBuilder<Post>(
                    future: post,
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                         Text(snapshot.data.name);
                      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                      }
                      // By default, show a loading spinner.
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
      );
  }
```

Comment: future: fetchPost,  and remove fetchPost() from initState.

Comment: I gave that a shot and no luck, still seems to be hanging without any error

Answer (score 1):

Man, I rewrite your code as I like

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

//import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
  String url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151';
  List data;

  Future<String> makeRequest() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    setState(() {
      var extractData = json.decode(response.body);
      data = extractData["results"];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    makeRequest();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pokemon List'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {},
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Search",
                  hintText: "Search",
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0))),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, i) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(data[i]["name"].toString().toUpperCase()),
                      subtitle: Text(data[i]["url"]),
                      //  leading:  CircleAvatar(
                      // backgroundImage:
                      //  NetworkImage(data[i]["picture"]["thumbnail"]),
                      //  ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => SecondPage(data[i])));
                      },
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  Map data;

  SecondPage(this.data);

  _SecondState createState() => _SecondState();
}

class _SecondState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchPost();
  }

  Map post;
  bool isLoad = true;

  _fetchPost() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoad = true;
    });
    var url = widget.data["url"];
    debugPrint(url);
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON.
      post = json.decode(response.body.toString());
      setState(() {
        isLoad = false;
      });
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.data["name"] + ' - ' + widget.data["url"])),
      body: _buildPokemon(context),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPokemon(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoad) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(post['name']),
          Text(post['weight'].toString()),
          Text(post['height'].toString()),
          Image.network(post['sprites']['front_default'])
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```